# ethernet controller not working on new dell vostro 2520 laptop

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am very new to ubuntu. just today I when i tried to plug in my lan cable it was showing nothing . the result of `sudo lshw -C network` showing Ethernet Controller under `*-network unclaimed`. In Settings > Network no wired connection is showing. please help

```
suravi@suravi-Vostro-2520:~$ lspci -nn |grep 0200
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your ethernet device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0200 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. thanks to [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661489):

> Ubuntu 11.04 - the Natty Narwhal
>
> A few weeks back I had my on board Realtek PCI express go out. I
>   thought the onboard chip had fried so I installed another Ethernet
>   card a ENLGA-1320 all was well until around 12:00pm today and then
>   flop, no Internet connection from it either. So I started my decent
>   into Google and finally got it working 5 hours later.
>
> Here's what didn't work, but things you may try to get it up and
>   working...for it seemed it was working for some just not for me.
>
> A cold start which info was gathered from this thread on it.
>   http://www.uluga.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1436667
>
> Giving that forum credit by linking it, I will supply the info below:
>
> Cold Start Instructions:
>
> - Shut down the machine
> - Unplug all cables from the tower(The power cable especially)
> - Hold the power button down for 30 seconds Then Release
> - Press the button a good time or two for good measure, wait 3 minutes.
> - Plug all cables back up and press the power button
> - Internet may or may not be active now.
>
> This didn't work for me, and if it did not for you lets continue on.
>   This is another post located in the thread linked above, ones again
>   I'll sum it up. Open a terminal and do the following.
>
> Check the model number of your Ethernet controller:
>
> ```
> :~$ lspci | grep Realtek
> 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Check the driver your kernel is loading:
>
> :~$ lsmod | grep r816*
> r8169 36489 0
> mii 4425 1 r8169
> Download the 8168 Linux drivers from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTL8111B/RTL8168B/RTL8111/RTL8168%3Cbr%3ERTL8111C/RTL8111CP/RTL8111D%28L%29%3Cbr%3ERTL8168C/RTL8111DP/RTL8111E%3Cbr%3ERTL8105E
> ```
>
> cd to the directory you downloaded the realtek driver:
>
> ```
> :~$ cd Downloads extract the files:
>
> :~$ tar -xvf r8168-8.020.00.tar.bz2 cd to the newly extracted folder:
>
> :~$ cd r8168-8.020.00 Auto compile the driver:
>
> :~$ sudo ./autorun.sh I highly doubt this is needed, because at this point my machine restarted its network connection on its own.
> ```
>
> However I will still include the optional commands to test the driver.
>
> ```
> :~$ sudo rmmod r8169
> :~$ sudo modprobe r8168
> :~$sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
> At this point your network should be up and running, if not do not take the following next two steps. Blacklist r8169:
>
> :~$ sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
> Append the following lines:
> #Blacklist Realtek RTL8111/8169 gigabit driver
> blacklist r8169
> Save and quit
> Update driver cache:
> :~$ update-initramfs -u
> Reboot, and see if correct driver has loaded:
> $ lsmod | grep r816*
> r8168 91629 0
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Ok so if that worked for you cool, however for me I was ones again met
>   with dismay and had to find another solution. This time around I'm
>   desperate this is my development box, but also sort of mad and just
>   going to do what it takes to get it up and running,
>
> http://www.webupd8.org/2009/06/how-to-manually-set-up-your-wired.html
>
> The link above is where most/parts of the following instructions came
>   from, must give credit where credit is due.
>
> ```
> Remove any drivers/modules installed i had both r8169 and r8168 installed so in terminal write
>
> :~$ sudo rmmod r8169
> sudo rmmod r8168
> So now I have no eth0 at this point. Remove network manager:
>
> sudo apt-get remove network-manager-gnome network-manager now in terminal type:
>
> :~$ ifconfig
> all I saw was lo listed and not eth0, again I was lost but I thought what the hey might as well continue on with the instructions
> ```
>
> that were provided by the link mentioned above. Set up manually the
>   `/etc/network/interfaces` in terminal type:
>       gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces I set up a static IP and even though All that was in the file was
>
> ```
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback I still appended the following to that file:
>
> auto eth0
> iface eth0 inet static
> address 192.168.1.10
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> gateway 192.168.0.1 Change eth0, address, and gateway to your own network values. Save the file and close it. For the static IP It
> ```
>
> needed to find the domain name servers(DNS). This is the function of
>   the `/etc/resolv.conf` file so you need to edit it. If the file
>   doesn't exist, create it. In terminal:
>
> ```
> gksu gedit /etc/resolv.conf In that file place the following:
>
> nameserver 208.67.222.222
> nameserver 208.67.220.220 Replace these values with your own DNS values. I just used googles DNS
>
> nameserver 8.8.8.8
> nameserver 8.8.4.4 Save and close the file. Download the 8168 Linux drivers from RealTek:
> ```
>
> http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTL8111B/RTL8168B/RTL8111/RTL8168%3Cbr%3ERTL8111C/RTL8111CP/RTL8111D%28L%29%3Cbr%3ERTL8168C/RTL8111DP/RTL8111E%3Cbr%3ERTL8105E
>
> cd to the directory you downloaded the realtek driver:
>
> ```
> :~$ cd Downloads extract the files:
>
> :~$ tar -xvf r8168-8.020.00.tar.bz2 cd to the newly extracted folder:
>
> :~$ cd r8168-8.020.00 Auto compile the driver:
>
> :~$ sudo ./autorun.sh Now restart the network in terminal :
>
> :~$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
> ```
>
> Ok at this point my pc fully black screened after resetting the
>   network, it was on but no body was home. So I shut it down manually by
>   holding the power button cut it back on and eth0 works perfect now,
>   and that's the built in one that went out on the mother board first.