# Internet connection drops after 10 seconds

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet, realtek

I have an issue with the wired connection in Ubuntu 20.04. When I restart the wired connection, the internet is connecting for 10 seconds and after that internet disconnected. **It happens after connecting to another ethernet**.
I've tested in Windows on the same device and the wired connection work perfectly.

`ifconfig`:

```
br-01eaafad0ac5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:c2:c2:d7:40  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-8af8a389b013: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.49.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.49.255
        ether 02:42:a3:bb:fd:20  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:13:f0:9d:0a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.125  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.17.0.255
        inet6 fe80::bdbd:d4d3:27b0:da2b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8c:0f:6f:72:74:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 72  bytes 15513 (15.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 304  bytes 25513 (25.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1613  bytes 148550 (148.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1613  bytes 148550 (148.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 40:9f:38:0c:4d:97  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx1062eb320a88: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::d8c2:1da0:643e:f5cf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 10:62:eb:32:0a:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4026  bytes 7045370 (7.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 265  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2740  bytes 1329710 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: 40:9f:38:0c:4d:97
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df100000-df103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 8c:0f:6f:72:74:2e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=172.17.0.125 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df004000-df004fff memory:df000000-df003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:6
       logical name: wlx1062eb320a88
       serial: 10:62:eb:32:0a:88
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic ip=192.168.43.3 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

`dmesg | grep e1000e`: Nothing

`dmesg | grep r81`

```
[    0.026270] percpu: Embedded 56 pages/cpu s192512 r8192 d28672 u524288
[    0.026275] pcpu-alloc: s192512 r8192 d28672 u524288 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.676015] libphy: r8169: probed
[    0.676174] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h, 8c:0f:6f:72:74:2e, XID 541, IRQ 126
[    0.676175] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    0.677083] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0
[    3.588250] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    3.709693] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[    3.986279] r8188eu 1-6:1.0 wlx1062eb320a88: renamed from wlan0
[    6.410031] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-200:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-200:00, irq=IGNORE)
[    6.609967] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[  319.190371] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[27285.099624] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[27292.060262] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-200:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-200:00, irq=IGNORE)
[27292.244453] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[27296.397106] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[29075.912170] r8188eu 1-6:1.0 wlx1062eb320a88: renamed from wlan0
[59818.035387] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[59821.142964] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-200:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-200:00, irq=IGNORE)
[59821.339009] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[59825.437233] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
```

`lsmod | grep r81`:

```
r8188eu               430080  0
lib80211               16384  1 r8188eu
cfg80211              778240  3 rtlwifi,mac80211,r8188eu
r8169                  77824  0
```

`apt-cache policy r8168-dkms`:

```
r8168-dkms:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.048.00-1ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
     8.048.00-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
     8.048.00-1 500
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: @waltinator there is no useful logs just info logs.

Comment: This sounds more like a network problem than an OS problem For example, if e.g. [your IP address was mistakenly allocated to the DHCP pool](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=112648) at the same time it was statically allocated elsewhere, you might see symptoms like you describe, and since your Windows partition has a different IP address it would not exhibit the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I set static IP but didn't work. @NathanielM.Beaver

Comment: @AhmadShahriari Please post output of `ifconfig` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `dmesg | grep e1000e`.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2449254

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver Done.

Comment: Thanks @AhmadShahriari this is quite helpful. Next, please post the output of `dmesg | grep r81`, `lsmod | grep r81`, and `apt-cache policy r8168-dkms`.

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver Added.

Comment: @AhmadShahriari Thanks. Last question: do you have some form of network access to run e.g. `apt install`, or do you need instructions that can be performed offline?

Comment: @AhmadShahriari First pass at the answer posted below, assuming you have internet. If you could also post the output of `modinfo r8169` and `uname -a` that would be helpful for other folks reading this question down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: install the `r8168-dkms` package:

```
apt install r8168-dkms
```

and then reboot to deactivate the old driver and activate the new one.
(This can also be done without rebooting,
but rebooting is simpler.)

Long version:
This appears to be a known bug in the `r8169` driver:

> ubuntu 20.4 - retransmitts with r8169
>
> i run some network-tests (iperf3) and noticed massive retransmitts in ubuntu
> 20.4 with kernel 5.4.0-29. I'm using module r8169 for network-adapter
>
> 03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1880076

> live iso 20.04 no wired network

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1875126

I think it may also be related to these upstream bug reports:

> An onboard network Realtek RTL8111E controller, which is served via r8169
> driver, doesn't provide a stable network connection on kernel versions 5.3
> (5.3.18-lp152.33-default openSUSE Leap 15.2) and 5.8 (5.8.1-3.1.g846658e).
> The workaround, mentioned in some similiar bug reports, to disable ASPM
> (pcie_aspm=off) doesn't stabilize the network.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209081

```
Starting from kernel 5.3-rc1, the r8169 driver oops during os boot.
I can not use the network.
```

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204343

If you need to reload the drivers without rebooting,
this can be done via these commands:

```
sudo rmmod r8169
sudo modprobe r8168
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

If it stops working after a reboot,
try this to make sure the `r8169` driver doesn't get loaded on start up:

```
echo 'blacklist r8169' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Related:

- [Upgraded to 20.04 and Lost Ethernet Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321398/upgraded-to-20-04-and-lost-ethernet-connection)
- [I clean installed 20.04 LTS but now I have no network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241785/i-clean-installed-20-04-lts-but-now-i-have-no-network)
- [Realtek R8169 driver Ubuntu 20.04 (with RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c))](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308793/realtek-r8169-driver-ubuntu-20-04-with-rtl8111-8168-8411-pci-express-gigabit-et)
- [Ethernet not working on Ubuntu - Driver r8169: link down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761027/ethernet-not-working-on-ubuntu-driver-r8169-link-down)
- [r8168/r8169 RealTek driver module troubles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052971/r8168-r8169-realtek-driver-module-troubles)
- [ethernet controller not working on new dell vostro 2520 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457668/ethernet-controller-not-working-on-new-dell-vostro-2520-laptop)